# HTML drop down menu not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm doing a drop-down menu in HTML using JavaScript and CSS. The problem I'm facing is the contents of drop-down menu get expanded when hovering outside the menu as well. So that I can't access the other contents of the page because it gets overlapped.

How can I solve this?

I can provide the screenshot.

[This is our website](http://temp.revollt.com/)

http://prntscr.com/inww2k

Comment: How about creating a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). and while you're reading that,, perhaps [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i've found your problem. Your main-menu is implemented as an unorderd list (ul) where each menu item is a list element (li). The side-menu which pops up upon hovering is also an unordered list but it is housed within the main-menu's list element.  Here is some crude code representing your layout:

```
<ul id='mainMenu'>
    <li> <a src='someaddress'>BOOKS</a>
        <ul id='sideMenu'>
            <li>For Children</li>
            <li>Another side menu item..</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
//rest of the main menu html
</ul>
```

If you inspect your HTML, this second unordered list (id='sideMenu' above) is actually visible beyond the boundaries of your main-menu border even in the hidden state and it seems that your hover event is placed on the main unordered list (id='mainMenu' above). In other words its working as expected based on the HTML content that the hover event is placed on.

There are 2 potential fixes i see here:

You could try to completely hide the side menu unordered list or even append it to the html using Jquery/DOM manipulation. Assuming the rest of your html for that mainMenu ul will be contained in the menu boundary.

Or probably the easier fix, you could change the hover event from the list element or li ( to the anchor tag which contains the link to the BOOKS page (it has class "icemega_active iceMenuTitle" in your html).

Comment: Thank you so much, the 1st solution DOM manipulation worked well.

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     $('.icesubMenu').hide();
     $('#icemegamenu .parent').mouseover(function() {
        $( this ).find('.icesubMenu').show();
     });
     $('#icemegamenu').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.icesubMenu').hide();
    });
});`